# I'm using SourceTree with GitHub. GitHub made me "upgrade" to PAT access. But I can't find the place in SourceTree to copy this PAT

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree with GitHub.  GitHub made me "upgrade" security to use Personal Access Token rather password. But I can't find the place in SourceTree to copy this PAT.  Meanwhile I'm looked out of my account